# How to print only the unique items in a list, those occurring once?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def get_distinct(original_list):
    distinct_list = []
    for i in original_list:
        if i not in distinct_list:
            distinct_list.append(each)
     return distinct_list

list_1 = [1,2,3,4,4,5,6,6]
print(get_distinct(list_1))
```

So I want it to print 1, 2, 3, 5 instead of 1,2,3,4,5,6

Comment: I'm hoping to use a function to carry this out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is good way to count things, e.g.:

```
from collections import Counter

def get_distinct(original_list):
    return [k for k, v in Counter(original_list).items() if v == 1]

In []:
list_1 = [1,2,3,4,4,5,6,6]
get_distinct(list_1)

Out[]:
[1, 2, 3, 5]
```

While in 3.6 this will be in the order expected `Counter()` doesn't make any order guarantees, if you need it in the same order as in `original_list` then you can create a `set` and use that to test uniqueness, e.g.:

```
def get_distinct(original_list):
    uniqs = {k for k, v in Counter(original_list).items() if v == 1}
    return [e for e in original_list if e in uniqs]
```

Comment: Nice, but this would be more readable: `print([item for item, count in Counter(list_1).items() if count == 1])`

Answer (score 2):

```
print([x for x in list_1 if list_1.count(x) == 1])
```

Comment: Note: Using `count()` this way is not very efficient - this is `O(n^2)`. However, for short lists this will not be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Although using [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is the best approach here, another option you can use is counting with a [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

def get_distinct(original_list):
    counts = defaultdict(int)

    for item in original_list:
        counts[item] += 1

    return [k for k, v in counts.items() if v == 1]
```

Which works as follows:

```
>>> get_distinct([1,2,3,4,4,5,6,6])
[1, 2, 3, 5]
```

If you want to guarantee order, you can use a [`collections.OrderedDict()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def get_distinct(original_list):
    counts = OrderedDict()

    for item in original_list:
        counts[item] = counts.get(item, 0) + 1

    return [k for k, v in counts.items() if v == 1]
```

Comment: This has a similar issue to `Counter()` in that order is not guaranteed, not sure if that is important to the OP.

Comment: @AChampion, Yeah I agree. In that case, I guess you could just fall back on the `OrderedDict`.

Comment: You could also do `counts[item] = counts.get(item, 0) + 1` to avoid the `if` condition.

Comment: @AChampion Ah yes forgot about `dict.get()`, I'll update my answer.